# Running Kotlin Code on SBT / Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, kotlin

I'm a huge fan of the PlayFramework, but I have limited experience with SBT / Scala. I've been trying to use Kotlin more, so I'm trying to get Kotlin Running on SBT / PlayFramework.

I've used Kotlin with the Gradle Build system, but that requires me to apply the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Not sure how to do the equivalent for SBT.

**Here is your basic build.sbt for Play.** How would I go about getting adding Kotlin?

```
name := """KotlinTestServer"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

I'd have to add `"org.jetbrains.kotlin" % "kotlin-stdlib" % "0.10.195"` as a library dependency, but what else?

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered going the opposite way. How about a play2 app built in maven. https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/ then Kotlin integration should be a lot more straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I was considering building with Gradle, which would allow the same thing. The Gradle team is actually officially working on play integration, but the project is going a little slower than I'd hoped. I'll look into the maven plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Gradle support for Play is documented here along with known issues: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html

Answer (score 12):

8 months late, but there is now: [Github kotlin-plugin](https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "kotlin-plugin" % "0.5")
```

Comment: Any comments anyone about how this worked for you in practice for your project?

Comment: looks like this plugin is not maintained anymore

Answer (score 0):

You must have some additional configuration to compile Kotlin code, like a plugin for Kotlin... but AFAIK that plugin doesn't exists.

I don't know if is possible to reuse Maven plugins inside SBT, that could work. Or you could contribute with your own SBT plugin gor Kotlin

Comment: I essentially need to do whatever the plugin does manually. Interesting idea about the maven plugin inside SBT. I'll look into that.

Comment: Ended up not panning out.

Comment: The plugin does now exist.  See other answer.